# MvvmLight EventToCommand is not supported in a WPF4?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I made super-simple demo project, to show what is my problem. I have just one view and viewmodel and two nuget packages. `MainWindow`, `MainWindowViewModel` and `Expression.Blend.Sdk`, `MvvmLightLibs`.

**My packages:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Expression.Blend.Sdk" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MvvmLightLibs" version="5.2.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

**C# code, so App and ViewModel:**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public string Title => "Main window";
    public ICommand LoadedCommand => new RelayCommand(Loaded);

    private void Loaded()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Loaded");
    }
}
```

**and MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmDemo1.WPF.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MvvmDemo1.WPF.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MvvmDemo1.WPF.ViewModels">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=LoadedCommand}" 
                                        PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="82,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Content="{Binding Title}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Here is my problem:**

> The type 'EventToCommand' from assembly 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform'
>   is built with an older version of the Blend SDK, and is not supported
>   in a Windows Presentation Framework 4 project.

[image]

The question is, can you help me with this?

Btw. I have this:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
```

because [on mvvmlight webpage](http://www.mvvmlight.net/installing/changes/) they suggested it (bottom of the page)

Comment: Recreated your sample, works as expected. My project is targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2. And I pulled in the references from the following folders: GalaSoft.MvvmLight | GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras | GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform -> `packages\MvvmLightLibs.5.2.0.0\lib\net45\`. `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation -> `packages\CommonServiceLocator.1.3\lib\portable-net4+sl5+netcore45+wpa81+wp8\`. `System.Windows.Interactivity -> `packages\Expression.Blend.Sdk.1.0.2\lib\net45\`. Make sure you have the same.

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi thanks for reply. I've 4.5.2 too. Here is my project: https://github.com/robertwojnar/MvvmDemo1 
Can you check this out?

Comment: Same, it runs without that error/warning.

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi thanks. What's your `xmlns:cmd` and `xmlns:i` ?

Comment: The same as the one mentioned in the question. I didn't change anything in the solution from GitHub other than doing a NuGet package restore.

Comment: The error is right in there.  Either target a compatible version of the framework or get an updated version of mvvmlight.

Comment: @Will What do you mean "updated"? Isn't it the latest version?

Comment: We're talking here about the simplest possible example of Interaction.Triggers and EventToCommand. I don't understand where's the catch :/

Comment: @robertwojnar Did you ever get this sorted out? I'm getting the same problem in a new project I'm working on that's using 4.5.2 and I'm using the latest version of mvvmlight.